# MySQL Question about limiting the result

Tags: mysql

I want to know how to limit the MySQL result. I can use "select * from students" to show all the students, but it is too many. I can add where condition, but it still many students after I use where to filter the result. Is it possible to return first 100 students, and order by first name. And next time, I want the first 101-200 ... ... instead of return all the result to me at once.

I know it can be done by programming, but I want to do it in SQL command, is it possible to do so? If not, any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to ask two questions, please ask two questions. It is very confusing for other users if two questions are asked in one thread. Besides, how are you going to accept two answers? Please split!

Comment: ok, I open another thread to discuss about scheduling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id1243725) clause, e.g.

```
#get first 100 rows
SELECT foo FROM bar LIMIT 0,100;

#get next 100 rows
SELECT foo FROM bar LIMIT 100,100;
```